# Compose Layout: Align relative to centered item (eg. toRightOf)

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way in Compose to align a composable next to a centered item without using `ConstraintLayout`?

I want to achieve this:
[image]

I could use a `Spacer` and `Weights` like this
[image]

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {

    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Button(...)
    Label(Modifier.weight(1f),...)
}
```

Problem is that I display the `Label` conditionally and if I hide the two elements with the weights, the button moves slightly.

Also not sure if using weights is producing more performance impact than the `ConstraintLayout` in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Modifier.weight` is the right way to create such a layout. I'm not sure if the performance is better than `ConstraintLayout`, but certainly not worse.

If you run into performance problems, you should create a problem on the google issue tracker, since that's how Compose is supposed to be used. Personally, I haven't encountered any performance problems related to `weight`, but the technology is fairly recent, so you can't completely rule out such a possibility.

In your case, you need to have some representation at any given time, to which you can apply `Modifier.weight`. You can use `if`-`else` and add `Spacer` in `else` case, but I prefer to use `Box` with optional content: it looks cleaner and will work correctly in case you add animation.

Default `Box` `contentAlignment` is `Alignment.TopStart`, which will work exactly as needed in your case, but in some other cases, you can override it or add more `Spacers` inside.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Button(...)
    Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) { 
        if (condition) {
            Label(...)
        }
    }
}
```